# solve complex equation for $x$ and $y$

Tags: complex-numbers

How to solve this?

I have tried to put all $z$s on one side,

but I don't have an idea to continue.

$$z^3-i(z-2i)^3=0$$

Comment: Expand it out..

Comment: how ? what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Hint: $(z-2i)^3 = z^{3} + 3z^2.(-2i) + 3z.(-2i)^2 +(-2i)^3$

Comment: I don't think expanding it is a good way to proceed. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
z^3 = i\cdot(z-2i)^3.
$$
Therefore $z$ is one of the three cube roots of $i(z-2i)^3$.

Observe that $(-i)^3 = i$ so $z$ is one of the three cube roots of $(-i)^3 (z - 2i)^3 = (-2-iz)^3$.

One of those three cube roots is $-2-iz$.

So either $z=-2-iz$ or $z$ is one of the other two cube roots.

If $z=-2-iz$ then $z(1+i) = -2$ so $z=-2/(1+i) = i-1$.

Since $z$ is one of the three cube roots of its cube and it's one of the three cube roots of $-2-iz$, the three cube roots of $i-1$ are what we seek.

What are the three cube roots of $i-1 = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos(135^\circ) + i\sin(135^\circ)\right)$.  Here we invoke de Moivre's theorem and seek the three numbers that are $135^\circ/3$ and this division is done modulo $360^\circ$.  That gives us
$$
45^\circ \text{ or } {45}^\circ \pm \frac{360^\circ} 3 = 45^\circ \text{ or } {-75}^\circ \text{ or } {+165}^\circ.
$$
Modulo $360^\circ$, that is the same as
$$
45^\circ \text{ or } 165^\circ \text{ or } 285^\circ,
$$
all differing from each other by a third of a circle.  So we have:
\begin{align}
\sqrt 2\left(\cos45^\circ + i \sin45^\circ\right) & = 1+i \\[10pt]
\sqrt2 \left(\cos165^\circ + i\sin165^\circ\right) & = \cdots \\[10pt]
\sqrt 2\left(\cos 185^\circ + i \sin185^\circ\right) & = \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: how do you get this : $$(−i)^3(z−2i)^3=(2i−z)^3(−i)^3(z−2i)^3=(2i−z)^3$$

Comment: this laste step

Comment: @MilošŽivković : Mistake in arithmetic.  I hope I've fixed it now. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: How to you get this one : $$i−1=cos(135^∘)+isin(135^∘)$$<br>Why isn't it $$cos(45^∘)$$

Answer (score 0):

Expand and then find the roots of the polynomial, just like you would for a real polynomial.

Comment: I disagree.  See my answer posted here. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $-i(z-2i)^3 = (i(z-2i))^3$, which is a perfect cube, leaving the left-hand side to be a sum of cubes.

Comment: So that means $$z^3 = -(i(z-2i))^3$$ ? And than I can get cube root out of these both sides ?

Comment: You could go that route, but when you take $ \sqrt[3]{(-1)}$, you have to remember there are 3 roots, not just 1. I would factor the sum of two cubes using $a^3 + b^3 =(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$z^3-i(z-2i)^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(1-i)z^3-6z^2+12iz+8=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(1+i)(z+(1-i))(-iz^2-(2-4i)z+4)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z+(1-i))(-iz^2-(2-4i)z+4)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z+(1-i)=0\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space -iz^2-(2-4i)z+4)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+i\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space z^2-(4+2i)z+4i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+i\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space z^2-(4+2i)z=-4i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+i\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space z^2-(4+2i)z+(3+4i)=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+i\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space (z-(2+i))^2=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+i\Longleftrightarrow \space\space\vee\space\space z-(2+i)=\pm\sqrt{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=-1+i \space\space\vee\space\space z=(2+i)\pm\sqrt{3}$$